# 'Foreign Keys' not displaying when using column_list in a model in Flask-admin

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

Using Flask-admin 1.6.0 I am having an issue when trying to display columns in a custom order using column_list within a model.

Without column_list, when I let Flask-admin display the columns automatically it shows the FK's and descriptions. (As shown in the first three columns).

[Foreign Keys displaying correcting in first three columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iYB4.png)

However, when I create a column_list and try to display DicCondition.description, DicMaterial.description and DicTray.description the table is blank. There are no errors shown in the terminal. (I have tried quoting 'DicMaterial.description' etc - This also does not work).

[Custom Column List with three FKs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF65R.png)

And the columns display blank:

[The columns display blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0AJ2.png)

What is strange (but expected behaviour) is that I can search / filter using these FK fields within column_searchable_list and column_filters. DicMaterial.description is resolving correctly in column_searchable_list and column_filters and returns valid results as shown below. (The description, which is not visible in the table has the entry Corex and matches rex; column_searchable_list can access the contents of DicMaterial.description. This is why I'm surprised it is not displaying in the column_list.

Here are the models I have:

```
class CsBoreholeSampleTray(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cs_borehole_sample_tray'
    __table_args__ = {u'schema': 'corestore'}

    borehole_sample_tray_id = db.Column(db.String(10), primary_key=True, unique=True)
    original_tray_id = db.Column(db.String(15))
    borehole_id = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    borehole_sample_top_depth_metres = db.Column(db.Numeric(6, 2))
    borehole_sample_bottom_depth_metres = db.Column(db.Numeric(6, 2))
    tray_type = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(u'corestore.dic_tray.code'), nullable=False, server_default=db.FetchedValue())
    percent_unallocated = db.Column(db.Numeric(3, 0))
    comments = db.Column(db.String(200))
    tray_material = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(u'corestore.dic_material.code'), nullable=False, server_default=db.FetchedValue())
    tray_condition = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(u'corestore.dic_condition.code'), nullable=False, server_default=db.FetchedValue())
    tray_weight_kg = db.Column(db.Numeric(4, 1))
    user_entered = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False, server_default=db.FetchedValue())
    date_entered = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False, server_default=db.FetchedValue())
    user_updated = db.Column(db.String(10))
    date_updated = db.Column(db.Date)

    dic_condition = db.relationship(u'DicCondition', primaryjoin='CsBoreholeSampleTray.tray_condition == DicCondition.code', backref=u'cs_borehole_sample_trays')
    dic_material = db.relationship(u'DicMaterial', primaryjoin='CsBoreholeSampleTray.tray_material == DicMaterial.code', backref=u'cs_borehole_sample_trays')
    dic_tray = db.relationship(u'DicTray', primaryjoin='CsBoreholeSampleTray.tray_type == DicTray.code', backref=u'cs_borehole_sample_trays')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.borehole_sample_tray_id)
```

and

```
class DicMaterial(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'dic_material'
    __table_args__ = {u'schema': 'corestore'}

    code = db.Column(db.String(1), primary_key=True, unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(25))
    status = db.Column(db.String(1), nullable=False, server_default=db.FetchedValue())
    user_entered = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False, server_default=db.FetchedValue())
    date_entered = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False, server_default=db.FetchedValue())
    user_updated = db.Column(db.String(10))
    date_updated = db.Column(db.Date)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.description)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.description)
```

Does anyone know how I can make the FK's display correctly in a custom ordered column_list? I think this might be a bug and have opened an issue on GitHub here: https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/issues/2313

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1):

I solved this and it was obvious.

In the column_list I should have been using:

- dic_material rather than DicMaterial.description,
- dic_condition rather than DicCondition.description, and
- dic_tray rather than DicTray.description